# Как получить оригинальные нативные объекты браузера, если они были изменены?

Tags: prototype, javascript, объекты, native

Собственно весь вопрос.
Своего рода анти-манки патчинг.
Как достать оригинальные объекты (Object, Array, Function, String, etc) и их прототипы, если они были  изменены \ расширены \ удалены?

Единственный возможный вариант, который сейчас вижу - это динамическое создание фрейма - вытаскивание из него нативных объектов - удаление фрейма на лету. Возможно тоже самое можно проделать с помощь Web Workers. Но они ie > 9, в них нет классов DOM, и сам по себе путь такой же как динамический фрейм.

Пример.

```
delete Object.prototype.constructor;
delete Object;

console.log(window.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.constructor); // undefined
// console.log(Object); // undefined

var frame = document.createElement('frame');
document.all[0].appendChild(frame);

var Object = frames[0].Object;
document.all[0].removeChild(frame);
console.log(Object);
```

Возможно есть иные пути решения?

Заранее спасибо.

**upd.**

Относительно *- не стоит использовать библиотеки которые лезут в нативы.*

Вы можете разрабатывать встраиваемую систему.
Допустим вы пишите библиотеку, которая в последствии будет использоваться кем-то и где-то. Какие еще библиотеки использует этот кто-то и где-то, неизвестно. И тогда становится, имхо, вполне разумно предусмотреть варианты, доступа к нативному окружения, учитывая тот факт, что еще до инициализации Вашей библиотеки, могут быть инициализированы иные, которые способны были бы на все (трудно сейчас привести конкретный пример, но откатившись на несколько лет назад, можно вспомнить prototype).
Тоже самое с песочницами. Ее введение, как средство отбрасывания yet-another-super-cool-class-prefix, сами по себе решают проблемы конфликтов между различными фреймворками\библиотеками.
Да, разумеется, решая конкретную задачу, можно опираться на свой рассудок.
Но при реализации встраиваемых вещей - неизвестно кто, как и куда будет встраивать. Почему бы не рассмотреть возможные варианты, даже с точки зрения просто интереса.

**upd.**

Вопрос и стоит в том, как попросить выдать движок эти начальные состояния объектов.
Ибо при условии, что наверняка не известно, когда именно будет инициализирована функция, что запишет начальные свойства объектов, нельзя быть уверенным, что они не будут подделаны до ее вызова. 
Пути по типу frame\workers очевидны, так как создается чистое новое окружение.
Но нельзя же быть всегда уверенным во всем на сто процентов, и быть может кто-то знает то, чего не знаешь ты. Посему я и интересуюсь у сообщества. Мало ли где то в global-object есть скрытый зарытый в **proto** или куда-либо объект, в котором сложено аккуратно в ряд, все это самое начальное окружение, да и дополненное свойствами запрета на модификацию\удаление\запись, а я о нем и не знаю. Или же существуют еще способы получения new window без явного создания онного. Например тот же frame по сути инициализируется лишь после добавления в документ, но не при самом создании элемента (createElement), что вызывает лишние телодвижения по его деинициализации после. С workers удобнее, но в них, как я уже описывал, нет нативных объектов браузера для работы с DOM, плюс они не поддерживаются старыми версиями тех же браузеров.

Comment: Из чистого интереса: а зачем вам? Мне почему-то кажется, что вам не должно хотеться такого, а вы, встретившись с проблемой,вместо честного решения собираетесь сделать какой-то грубый хак. Я неправ?

Comment: Допустим в проекте используется сразу несколько библиотек \ фреймворков. И некоторые из них подменяют оригинальные объекты браузера. Есть необходимость использовать нативные реализации классов и методов браузера, не избавляясь от библиотек, и не переписывая их код. 
Это как пример.
Самой задачи не стоит (во всяком случае пока), но что мешает рассмотреть возможные варианты решения?

Comment: Ну, подменяют, а в собственно чём проблема? Откуда берётся эта самая необходимость? Что не выходит с подменёнными объектами?

Если проблемы нет, а вопрос чисто теоретически, так и напишите. Для production-кода игра в «кто круче» — не имеет смысла. А вот если чтобы разобраться как что работает, тут другое дело.

Comment: Собственно вопрос и задан для того, чтобы рассмотреть пути, кои бы не выглядели настолько грязными. 

Ваше же определение относительно честного решения весьма не верно. Ситуации различные бывают. И в подобной будут не правы в первую очередь те, кто подменят нативности, нежели те, кто пытается до них достучаться.

Comment: @VladD Ну, а Вы умеете в теоритическое размышление, ради того, чтобы придумать решение той или иной не стандартной задачи? Или всегда идете по пути меньшего сопротивления? 

Вопрос не стоял в том, что мешает. 
Вопрос в возможных путях.
Если Вам это не интересно, или у вас нет дополнительных ответов, зачем засорять тред?

Comment: Умею, умею. Но чтобы не засорять, как вы изящно выразились, тред, вот вам [классика](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) по поводу игр в «кто круче», а я удаляюсь.

Comment: >  так и напишите. Для production-кода игра в «кто круче» 
По моему, за решением конкретных задач, люди идут конкретно к специалистам. С ТЗ, и грандом. На фриланс-биржи, например.
А сервисы Q&A сами по себе и есть теоретические.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что вопрос без предварительной записи(да и там все непросто) как-то решается, дело в том, что в js эти самые native не то чтобы совсем native (а те что менять нельзя уже и так неизменяемые), придти к бессмысленности попыток решения (и к осознанности возможной необходимости без iframe)   можно попытавшись решить сию проблему для серверных движков типа nodejs - c одной стороны для них нет никаких iframe, с другой, понятие "native" становится очень расплывчато. Для ноды решение похожее - тредовая либа.

Второй вариант - запретить менять свойства нативных объектов при инициализации (правда этот запрет будет распространяться и на код самого тюремщика), доступно вроде и для v8 и для spidermonkey, для IE не знаю.

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) в той задаче про TopMostWindow есть одно большое упущение - в сети супермаркетов есть администратор и операторы, и если уж компы позволяют всякие извращения, то почему бы просто все программы кроме одной, самой главной, не запихать в виртуальную машину ? И оператор девайса сам в таком случае решает. про задачи [[@vldmir](/users/22591/vldmir)](/users/22591/vldmir) я примерно так-же думаю, не стоит использовать библиотеки которые лезут в native (кроме может быть полифилов и то...), бить по рукам в общем всех кто ответсвенен. а для песочниц... В общем, не зря jsfiddle сделали отдельный фрейм на отдельном домене, в блоге даж писали.

Кстати, от использования prototype меня как раз оттолкнуло  то, что он вольно обходится с "несвоими" (c) объектами, вряд-ли бы вам понравился фреймворк, который зачем-то умножает все целые  числа на 2 во всех свойствах всех объектов вашего кода :), мне интересно было бы решить эту проблему но я, как уже сказал, не могу решить философскую проблему - какие свойства native, а какие нет. Я понимаю - состояние прототипов до исполнения любого кода можно посчитать native, но тогда и решением будет - тупо записать всё. Мне кажется в свете такого решения попросить движок выдать "нач" состояние - лучше.

Comment: @eicto: Смысл текста, на который я ссылался, таков: не нужно пытаться обойти другие части сложной системы. Части системы должны сотрудничать. Иначе всегда найдётся более хитрая часть системы, которая «выиграет», а в проигравших будет только пользователь.

Comment: да смысл понятен :) просто пример неудачный. Программисты часто забывают что программы это не просто абстрактные сущности выполняющие задачи для компов, а нечто выполняющее задачи для людей, и что в самых суперсложных системах всегда есть оператор, единственная полностью автоматическая система из мне известных это жизнь(бытиё) (в полном понимании, с планетами и прочими объектами) и то некоторые утверждают что есть суперадминистратор.

Comment: @eicto: Если вы прочитаете и комментарии к тексту, там упомянуты варианты, обходящие виртуальную машину :)

Программы, конечно, намного проще и тупее, чем мы о них привыкли думать. И именно поэтому в случае, который мы обсуждаем тут, мне кажется, что правильный ответ — программисту НЕ ДОЛЖНО хотеться обойти другие библиотеки. Если ему хочется низкоуровневый хак, это прямое указание на то, что он делает что-то не так, и его задача решается по-другому.

Приведёте контрпример?

Comment: да, контр-пример -  операционная система, она должна уметь по своему желанию вмешиваться в работу других процессов. как-раз нечто похожее на желание @vldmir она и делает. Для браузерного js операционная система - браузер и чуть выше движок js. в спеке es5 ничего подобного не описано, это значит, что если подобная фича(ту которую желает @vldmir) и может быть, то она должна быть реализована фичей движка. И такие фичи есть - iframe и треднутые процессы.

Comment: @eicto: С ОС понятно, здесь вы пишете не приложение, а ОС. Для браузера, если вам нужен низкий уровень, возможно, вы пишете плагин, а не сайт. Но всё же вернёмся из аналогий к задаче: для чего мог бы понадобиться сайту (не плагину) «эксклюзивный» доступ к базовым объектам?

Comment: @VladD для песочницы как я понял. практической пользы я в таких играх не вижу, кроме как научиться каким-то деталям, vldmr в принципе преуспел в этом, так-что такой путь самообучения вполне имеет право на жизнь. Кстати почему вы думаете что это "не плагин" ? Я вот например подозреваю что речь идет как-раз о каком-нить расширении к хрому.

Comment: @eicto: Если это плагин, то он уж может получить все нужные объекты в контексте браузера при загрузке самого браузера.

Как путь самообучения — это да, но мне это  кажется вопросом уровня «как мне сделать `eval` в чистом C» (ответом на который всегда было «вам не нужен `eval` в чистом С»).